# Creating classes and using them into project

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of button inside my application and for every button i need to create onClickListener, this will incerase line of code's.

So i create a class for onClickListener below:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.View;

    public class OnClickListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

        Activity current;
        Class<?> goTo;

        public OnClickListener(Activity arg0, Class arg1){
            this.current = arg0;
            this.goTo = arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(current, goTo);
        }

}
```

and now i want to go to next activity when button click's but when i put this line `startActivity(intent);` compiler shows error `The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type OnClickListener`

I dont know where i am going wrong and what i am missing. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in another way too, let your class implement the `OnClickListener` interface and then implement `onClick(...)` method, an in that method, switch on view's id like this:

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.btn1:
               ...
           case R.id.btn2:
               ...
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`startActivity` could not be found in the current context because your class is not an `Activity` (`startActivity` is a method of the `Activity` class).
Have a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to know more about `Activity` class.

Back to your problem: If `current` member variable is well set then you could just do the following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(current, goTo);
    current.startActivity (intent);
}
```

Comment: @DownVoter, a comment please?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am tried it but this is not starting next activity yet. I think there is somthing wrong with my class variable.
I declair like this `Class<?> goTo` is it right way?

Comment: @techiServices - let me get this straight.  Are you saying that stupid downvotes are funny?  That they are a good thing?

Comment: @techiServices This is not how Stackoverflow works! Down votes are not funny and are mainly meant to keep the high quality answers

Comment: @Stephen C. Not sure how you come to the query 'that they are a good thing' from 'lol it wasnt me but thanks for the petty downvote'.  Does that sound like stupid downvotes are funny?

Comment: @Pari My answer assumes the `current` activity is well set. There might be something else fishy with another bit of code that is not in the question

Comment: @techiServices - I read your comment as laughing that at the downvote on this question, and thanking the person who did it.  If that is not what you actually meant, you should express yourself more clearly.  Besides, you have no way of **knowing** who upvoted / downvoted which question.  SO votes are anonymous.  Furthermore, it is offensive to accuse specific people of voting for bad motives.

Answer (score -1):

Use the name of your activity as a prefix such as `MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: but this is a class how can i use activity as a prefix?

Comment: You specify the classname of your activity.  Then use `this` to reference the current instance.

Comment: @Pari You class has to be an `Activity` if you want do that. Check the details in my answer below

Comment: @techiServices Using `this` won't help at all. The class where the cal l is made is not an activity