# Using intent into non activity class

Tags: java, android

After trying a lot i decided to ask question on stackoverflow, I create a class for using on button click and start an intent from this class.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class OnClickListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Activity current;
    Object goTo;

    public OnClickListener(Activity arg0, Activity arg1){
        this.current = arg0;
        this.goTo = arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(current, goTo.getClass());
        current.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and passing parameter like this:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.class2_btn);
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(class1.this, class2);
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

why this is not working? after clicking button why this is not going to next class?
Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating classes and using them into project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850344/creating-classes-and-using-them-into-project)

Comment: Have you declared your new activity in manifest? Can you post the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some points i want to figure out here :

1. As you are using **startActivty()**, as the name suggests it is for activity not for simple class as you are trying here.Activity is like an UI that you can start but simple class is like a **Model** class they are not going start like activity.
2. If you will using activity in place of class then it will defiitely work.In that case you do not need to pass any argument just you can give name directly like below:

**Intent intent = new Intent(current_activity.this, target_activty.class);
current.startActivity(intent);**

1. If you **class2** is an activity then you should give it directly to startActivty() as i sated in above point not it's object like you did.And also ass this activity into menifest file.

Comment: That's what I thought at first sight, but please note that even if she declares `Object goTo`, the listener's constructor only allows an `Activity` parameter that is assigned to `goTo`

Answer (score 0):

You should post the whole code, and use more descriptive names instead of `Class1` and `Class2`. Anyway if your code compiles, both `Class1` and `Class2` are really descendents of `Activity`, because `OnClickListener` constructor only allows such.

Since you declare your button in XML, I suggest you add

```
android:onClick="goToActivity2"
```

to your layout, and then the following to your *current* Activity

```
public void goToActivity2(View button) {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
}
```

It's more polished and far less code. Anyway you should really review your question.